# border-radius on chrome V 45.0

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am using some browser build on chrome 45
I can't get border-radius work.
Any help please?

```
<form class="form-signin" action="" method="post" id="login_form">
    <div class="form-signin-heading text-center">
something
    </div>
</form>
```

style.css

```
.form-signin {
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-width: 330px;
    width: 330px;
    height: auto;
    background: brown;
    margin: 100px auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I tried -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

But its not working

Any idea please?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your problem is with the border radius? It looks like the code works just fine.

Comment: Agree, nothing wrong with your `border-radius` ... give the form a height by adding content to it and it will show up

Comment: The code dosn't work on the browser build on chrome 45!

Comment: Add posted an answer. Does that one work for you?

Comment: @jcoder1200, are you able to add a working example? (jsfiddle or snippet will be great)

Comment: Are you sure that your style has not overridden with other css's class/inline?

Comment: Please note that might be chrome v.45 doesn't support radius, any work around?